# C++ partially filled dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory

So I have a partially filled array, with a set of functions to write for it.

Basically, the array acts like this. An integer is added into the next available free space, when capacity is reached, the array is doubled and size, and all elements are added into the new one.

```
            +---+---+---+---+
elementData  | 6 | 2 | 4 |  |
            +---+---+---+---+

            +---+       +---+
   capacity | 4 |  size | 3 |
            +---+       +---+
```

It's created as such.

```
int ar[5] = {6, 2, 4, 7, 3};
PFArray pf;

cout << "==== Test addElement() ===\n";

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    cout << "Insert " << ar[i] << ": ";
    pf.addElement(ar[i]);
    displayResult(pf);
}
```

And the `addElement()` function I've attempted to write looks like this.

```
void PFArray::addElement(int elt)
{
    if (size == capacity)
    {
        int *resized = new int[size*2];
        capacity = size*2;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            resized[i] = elementData[i];
        elementData = resized;
        delete [] resized;
    }
    elementData[size++] = elt;
}
```

I'm running into two errors. One, at the beginning of each line, a 0 is being added into the array.

```
==== Test addElement() ===
Insert 6: [0,6,]  -- size=2, capacity=2
Insert 2: [0,6,2,]  -- size=3, capacity=4
Insert 4: [0,6,2,4,]  -- size=4, capacity=4
Insert 7: [0,6,2,4,7,]  -- size=5, capacity=8
Insert 3: [0,6,2,4,7,3,]  -- size=6, capacity=8
```

Two, I'm getting an error `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on the line `elementData[size++] = elt;`.

If someone could point me to what I'm doing wrong, it would be greatly appreciated. Just for reference, I'm fairly new to C++ as a language.

The behavior of `addElement()` is as follows.

> Inserts a new element elt at the next available/empty slot in the array. If the current array has reached its capacity, a copy of the array is created having twice the capacity of the old array first, then the new element is inserted in the new array.  You make elementData to point to the new array (of course).  But you must also DELETE the old array to avoid memory leak. You also have to set capacity and size appropriately.

I've tried to include all code that I thought was relevant, however if you need me to provide more, I'd be happy too!

P.S. I am aware of Vectors, but would like to use this methodology for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Unless your purpose is just to learn how raw arrays work, use `std::vector` and don't waste your time managing size/capacity etc.

Comment: @SteveFallows just edited the post to say this, unfortunately I cannot use a vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
elementData = resized;
delete [] resized;
```

There, you have deleted the array assigned to `elementData` and then you write to it:

```
elementData[size++] = elt;
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Zdeslav says, you write to a deleted array. The correct way is:

```
delete [] elementData;
elementData = resized;
```

The first error seems to be in the displayResult() code, but you have not included his code.